# subdomain redirection to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can redirect subdomain to wordpress?

i have main page at *example.com*, and created subdomain for wordpress *mywordpress.example.com*, created database, installed wordpress, files are there but it doesn't work. It directs to main page *example.com" and i SHOULD redirect this to wordpress.. I tried to find answer at worpress site, entered this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried to solve problem by some tutorials and still don't understand what and where i should change. I got htacces file, wp_admin and what next?

Comment: Did you tried to do an fresh install on the subfolder the subdomain ? Also, did you tried to use wp multisite? Seems to fit well on this problem

Comment: Wordpress is only installed here: mywordpress.example.com.

Comment: It's in public html. There is no css, js,  but There is test from index.html at mywordpress.example.com. At example.com i don't need Wordpress. I really need step by step, because i don't know what am i doing :-)

Comment: Is the subdomain set up as a subdirectory, i.e. can you navigate to example.com/mywordpress?

Comment: No, you can't..

Comment: So i should make this subdirectory, there unpack Wordpress and install it again?

Answer (score 0):

First, set your .htaccess file to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Next, look in the Options table in the database and make sure "siteurl" and "home" (the first couple of entries) are set to the address of your subdomain.

If this doesn't work, start over - remove all the files and the database and follow these steps:

1. Create a subdomain.  This means you can visit subdomain.example.com and you are staring at the nothing which is the root folder of that site.  You test this before you install WordPress, otherwise you don't know if WordPress is your problem or not.
2. Establish FTP access to the root directory of your subdomain and confirm it works.
3. Create a database.  Make a note of the name.   Create a database user.  Make note of the username and password.  Give this user full privileges over the database.
4. Upload a fresh copy of the WordPress.  Edit the wp-config.php file to include the correct db name, db user, db password.
5. Now you should be able to visit the subdomain and see a prompt to install WordPress.
   Good luck!